# Permissions within categories for SP 2013 calendar

Tags: 2013, calendar, calendar-view

I have a SP 2013 calendar based on categories, 6 in total, can I permission each category to only to be used by a predetermined set of users?

For example:

The category 1 calendar view can only be edited by people in the User1 group.

The category 2 calendar view can only be edited by people in the User2 group.

And so on....

Answer (score 0):

If the category is a field in the calendar entry then no you can't.  The only way I could think of doing something like this is to create 6 calendars, one for each category.  Then set all users to read, and the users you want to use the category to edit.  Then use a calendar overlay to display the combined view of all 6 calendars.  This gets sloppy when users need to be able to select from multiple categories because they have make sure they put the right event on the right calendar.